# R - dplyr - code to run a number of very similar queries...?

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Alan", "Bob", "Christine", "David", "Erica"),
  Gender = c("M", "M", "F", "M", "F"),
  Star_Sign = c("Aquarius", "Capricorn", "Aquarius", "Libra", "Leo"),
  City = c("London", "Paris", "Berlin", "London", "Paris"),
  Blood_Group = c("A", "AB", "B", "O", "A"),
  Hours_Worked = c(2000, 1600, 0, 100, 200),
  Salary = c(100000, 20000, 0, 500, 4000)
)

Name_Summary <-         df %>% group_by(Name)        %>% summarise(Hours_Worked = sum(Hours_Worked), Average_Salary = mean(Salary))
Gender_Summary <-       df %>% group_by(Gender)      %>% summarise(Hours_Worked = sum(Hours_Worked), Average_Salary = mean(Salary))
Star_Sign_Summary <-    df %>% group_by(Star_Sign)   %>% summarise(Hours_Worked = sum(Hours_Worked), Average_Salary = mean(Salary))
City_Summary <-         df %>% group_by(City)        %>% summarise(Hours_Worked = sum(Hours_Worked), Average_Salary = mean(Salary))
Blood_Group_Summary <-  df %>% group_by(Blood_Group) %>% summarise(Hours_Worked = sum(Hours_Worked), Average_Salary = mean(Salary))
```

Obviously this works fine for a small number of fields. If, however, I've got 100 different fields (say) to do this for, it becomes very unwieldy.

I'd like to think that there is a way to loop through the list of fields and produce these summaries for each field, using some code to generate (and name the summaries), but I don't think I know how to do this. Can anyone help please?

Thanks
Alan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a list of the columns you want to group by as a character vector:

```
vars_to_group_by <- names(df)[1:5]
```

You could iterate over them (I'm using `purrr::map()` but you could use `lapply()` or a loop), and use this `rlang` pattern to convert strings >> symbols >> properly evaluated variables.

```
library(tidyverse)

map(vars_to_group_by, sym) %>% 
  map(~ df %>% 
        group_by(!!.x) %>% 
        summarise(avg_salary = mean(Salary),
                  avg_hours = mean(Hours_Worked),
                  avg_hourly_wage = avg_salary / avg_hours))
```

You get an unnamed list back, because the vector going in was unnamed.

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  Name      avg_salary avg_hours avg_hourly_wage
  <fct>          <dbl>     <dbl>           <dbl>
1 Alan          100000      2000            50  
2 Bob            20000      1600            12.5
3 Christine          0         0           NaN  
4 David            500       100             5  
5 Erica           4000       200            20  

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  Gender avg_salary avg_hours avg_hourly_wage
  <fct>       <dbl>     <dbl>           <dbl>
1 F           2000       100             20  
2 M          40167.     1233.            32.6

[[3]]
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Star_Sign avg_salary avg_hours avg_hourly_wage
  <fct>          <dbl>     <dbl>           <dbl>
1 Aquarius       50000      1000            50  
2 Capricorn      20000      1600            12.5
3 Leo             4000       200            20  
4 Libra            500       100             5  

[[4]]
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  City   avg_salary avg_hours avg_hourly_wage
  <fct>       <dbl>     <dbl>           <dbl>
1 Berlin          0         0           NaN  
2 London      50250      1050            47.9
3 Paris       12000       900            13.3

[[5]]
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Blood_Group avg_salary avg_hours avg_hourly_wage
  <fct>            <dbl>     <dbl>           <dbl>
1 A                52000      1100            47.3
2 AB               20000      1600            12.5
3 B                    0         0           NaN  
4 O                  500       100             5
```

You could add names based on `vars_to_group_by` either before or after the `map()` calls.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work. I might want to do some other things with this output, but I'll have a little play with it first (on the large dataset I have in front of me).

Comment: Yea I know how that goes, the SO example is never the real world. Comment back if something isn't clicking, hopefully this pattern is extensible to other data manipulations

Comment: Thanks. One thing I'd like to be able to do is to have two fields instead of one inside the summarise() statement - have amended my original posting to give an example - but presumably (?) the syntax you used above would still cope fine because I could just modify what's in the summarise() part of it.

I'd also like to know if there's an easy way to turn these summaries into a series of graphs (histogram/line graph), churned out automatically, one graph for each field that I'm summarising, but I'm wondering if that's something I should post as a separate question.

Comment: You were on the right track for additional `summarise()` info. You could definitely make a ggplot for each new data frame and stick them all together, I like `?cowplot::plot_grid()` a lot, but there are other options like `egg` and `patchwork`

Answer (score 3):

We could use the `group_by_at` which can take a string as input

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(names(df)[-6], ~ df %>%
                       group_by_at(.x) %>%
                       summarise(avg_salary = mean(Salary)))
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  Name      avg_salary
#  <fct>          <dbl>
#1 Alan          100000
#2 Bob            20000
#3 Christine          0
#4 David            500
#5 Erica           4000

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  Gender avg_salary
#  <fct>       <dbl>
#1 F           2000 
#2 M          40167.

#[[3]]
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  Star_Sign avg_salary
#  <fct>          <dbl>
#1 Aquarius       50000
#2 Capricorn      20000
#3 Leo             4000
#4 Libra            500

#[[4]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  City   avg_salary
#  <fct>       <dbl>
#1 Berlin          0
#2 London      50250
#3 Paris       12000

#[[5]]
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  Blood_Group avg_salary
#  <fct>            <dbl>
#1 A                52000
#2 AB               20000
#3 B                    0
#4 O                  500
```